# Changing roles in Netsuite via Suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to do the following:
*Create custom role field called 'roletype' (string)
*Create a map/reduce script which triggers when a role is saved, containing following logic:
-Via saved search get all roles which have the same roletype
-Foreach of these copy all permissions off of the mutated role

Is it possible to do this via suitescript? How can I obtain the list of permissions via a role record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a search to get the roles and their permissions by adding two columns:

Permission : gives you the name of the permission (ex: Accounting Lists, Deleted Records...)

Level : gives you the permission level (ex: Edit, Full...)

But the problem you will face is that the Role record type is available on SuiteScript only to do searches, this means you can not Load and Edit a role using Scripting.

Check the help article:

SuiteCloud Platform > SuiteScript > SuiteScript Records Guide > SuiteScript Supported Records > Lists > Role

> Supported Functions
>
> This record is not fully scriptable. Only search is permitted. The
> Role record is supported in all search APIs, excluding the duplicate
> search APIs.